# Can't update Mongo Collection in Meteor from within a function

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a webhook set up that lives in imports/api in my application. This is a Stripe webhook and I’m trying update Campaign collection. I’m using a Meteor method to make this call however nothing happens. If I add the call back to it, I receive no error or results. However if I take this same Meteor Method an include it in main.js on the server in a Meteor startup function it runs fine. I’ve also tried just using the update function for a collection and it won’t work either. Main.js includes this file and I cannot figure out why this doesn’t work nor will push an error. The most important part of this line is the bottom where Paid == true, this is where the logic is. The console will spit out the information but the method won’t run. What could be the issue?

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { Picker } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker';
import {Campaign} from '../api/campaigns';

let campaignID;
let chargeAmount;
let chargeID;
let hasPaid = false;

//This will run outside the updateCampaign function fine and works as expected
Campaign.update({_id: "BAxBhk4ae3AdHxxEQ"}, {$set: {chargeTrx: "chargeID", amount: "555"}});


function updateCampaign(){

  //these consoles will print and prove the function runs
  console.log('campaignID type:' +  campaignID)
  console.log('chargeIDtype:' +  chargeID)
  console.log('amount type:' +  chargeAmount)

  //doesn't work even with strings prefilled
  Campaign.update({_id: "BAxBhk4ae3AdHxxEQ"}, {$set: {chargeTrx: "chargeID", amount: "333"}});

  //This didn't run either but would run outside of this function
  Meteor.call("updateCampaignForPayment", campaignID, chargeAmount, chargeID, (err, result) => {
    if (err){
      console.log('error')
    }
  });



}

// Middleware declaration
Picker.middleware(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '10MB',
  verify: function(req,res,buf) {
    var url = req.originalUrl;
    if (url.startsWith('/webhook')) {
      req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      let newResponse = req.rawBody;   

      //stripe returns to 2 objects, this makes it two arrays to parse it
      let parsedResponse = JSON.parse('[' + newResponse.replace(/}{/g, '},{') + ']');
      parsedResponse = parsedResponse[0].data.object;

      //break down two further objects
      if (parsedResponse.object == "charge"){
        chargeID = parsedResponse.id;
        hasPaid = parsedResponse.paid;
        chargeAmount = parsedResponse.amount / 100;
      }
      else if (parsedResponse.object == "checkout.session"){
        let campaignIDArray = parsedResponse.success_url.split('/');
        campaignID = campaignIDArray[5];
      }
      // If user has paid, update campaign
      if (hasPaid == true && chargeID && campaignID && chargeAmount){
        console.log(hasPaid, chargeID, campaignID, chargeAmount)
        //
        updateCampaign();
      }
    }
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any calls outside of the current Meteor environment (such as in callback functions or middleware handlers) to a construct, which requires Meteor environment, are to be bound using the Meteor environment.

In your case this seems to be `updateCampaign`, because it makes calls to the Meteor-Mongo Collection:

```js
const updateCampaign = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
  const updated = Campaign.update({_id: "BAxBhk4ae3AdHxxEQ"}, {$set: {chargeTrx: "chargeID", amount: "333"}});

  const callResult = Meteor.call("updateCampaignForPayment", campaignID, chargeAmount, chargeID);
})
```

Please also note, that the collection inside this function is running in async mode and only within Meteor environment code you can write code in a sync way and let it handle the async. You can always "wait" for the result there using `async/await`:

```js
function async updateCampaign(){
  const updated = await Campaign.update({_id: "BAxBhk4ae3AdHxxEQ"}, {$set: {chargeTrx: "chargeID", amount: "333"}});

  //This didn't run either but would run outside of this function
  const callResult = await Meteor.call("updateCampaignForPayment", campaignID, chargeAmount, chargeID);
}
```

or you use `Promise.await`, if you want to avoid `async/await`:

```js
function updateCampaign(){
  const updated = Promise.await(Campaign.update({_id: "BAxBhk4ae3AdHxxEQ"}, {$set: {chargeTrx: "chargeID", amount: "333"}}))

  //This didn't run either but would run outside of this function
  const callResult = Promise.await(Meteor.call("updateCampaignForPayment", campaignID, chargeAmount, chargeID))
}
```

Readings:

https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment

https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call

https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#promises

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/promise